# what are the terminologies for different types of homework?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

There are different types of homework for students:

> 1. they are asked to solve problems in theory
> 2. Write composition
> 3. make handicrafts

What certain vocabulary can be used for each one of these tasks?

Comment: Homework is any assignment not performed at school.  You may multiply your categories indefinitely -- prepare for a debate, learn lines of a play, write lab reports, and so on.  Please give us an idea of the different vocabulary you expect and how you would use it.

Comment: I just need certain words that would fit the three types of homework I have just mentioned

Comment: The two categories of homework are *done* and *not done*. Correction: the single category of homework is *not done*.

Comment: I'd call them: "a <subject> problems assignment", "a writing assignment", "a project"

Answer (score 2):

These are by no means the only terms for the examples you listed, but in my studies I have heard them called as such:

```
1. solving problems in theory: "problem sets" (mostly in physics or math)
2. write compositions: "paper" (as in, "I have to write a paper.")
3. make handicrafts: "project," or perhaps "arts and crafts project"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is the testing of an idea, it is 'experiment'. If it involves numbers, it is 'calculations'.
2. Writing skill or essay writing.
3. Art and design or Practical creativity.